# Wrong condition getting successful in PHP file

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have made a simple API through PHP to provision and check connection to server.

Here is the Code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
require_once("common.php");
$api_get="*******************";
$api_post="**********************";

if (isset($_GET["apikey"])){
    if ($_GET["apikey"]=="$api_get"){
        // Takes raw data from the request
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        // Converts it into a PHP object
        $data = json_decode($json,true);
        $post=$data["api_secret"];
        if ($api_post==$post){
            $_SESSION["status"]="authenticatedfor:".$_GET["command"];
            $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["username"];
            $_SESSION["password"]=$_POST["password"];
            $_SESSION["quota"]=$_POST["quota"];
            $_SESSION["email"]=$_POST["email"];
            if ($_GET["command"]="createacct"){
                header("Location:createaccount");
                exit;
            }
            elseif ($_GET["command"]="terminateacct"){
                header("Location:terminateacc");
                exit;
            }
            elseif ($_GET["command"]="suspendacct"){
                header("Location:suspendacc");
                exit;
            }
            elseif ($_GET["command"]="unsuspendacct"){
                header("Location:unsuspendacc");
                exit;
            }
            elseif ($_GET["command"]="sync"){
                header("Location:sync");
                exit;
            }
            elseif ($_GET["command"]="accessreset"){
                header("Location:passwordreset");
                exit;
            }
            elseif ($_GET["command"]="verifyconn"){
                header("Content-Type: application/json");
                $data=array("response" => "success");
                echo json_encode($data);
                exit;
            }
            else {
                header("Content-Type: application/json");
                $data=array("response" => "no_command");
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
        }
        else {
            header("Content-Type: application/json");
            $data=array("response" => "wrong_secret");
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
    else {
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        $data=array("response" => "wrong_key");
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
else {
    header("Content-Type: application/json");;
    $data=array("response" => "no_key");
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
?>
```

When I make CURL JSON request with all correct credentials, response comes "no_key" and when I write api_get or api_post wrong, it displays "wrong key" and "wrong secret".
I am making HTTP requests like `curl -X POST https://hostname.com/auth?command=verifyconn&apikey=*********************** -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"api_secret":"********************"}'`

Can anyone point out what I am missing?

Comment: can you test your api using third party client such as postman?

Comment: I am testing it through ReqBin which is third party I suppose...

Comment: that's ok. Its not issue. But you are getting api wrong key error. That makes sense. you should focus on that, why are you getting this error

Comment: I am getting no_key response when entering right credentials(both api and secret). That means ```isset($_GET["apikey"]``` gets false but why? When I write key or secret wrong, this condition still gets true but only gets false when both credentials are correct.

Comment: you should check query string

Comment: curl -X POST 'https://hostname.com/auth?command=verifyconn&apikey=***********************' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"api_secret":"********************"}'

Comment: Start with `var_dump($_GET);`, any url rewriting/redirection going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
curl -X POST 'https://hostname.com/auth?command=verifyconn&apikey=***********************' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"api_secret":"********************"}'
```

Comment: Same response. Its the same I used!

Comment: You need to add  URL in single quote. Example: 'https://hostname.com/auth?command=verifyconn&apikey=***********************'

Comment: I used yours too. The response is same! no_key

Comment: http://prntscr.com/22sktkz

Comment: It seems you have directly pasted ********* . I have masked it to hide the real Keys. You can enter values in $api_get and $api_post and then try

Comment: Hey, It's working fine with keys. I found one more issue: for all If condition you need to write == instead of =. (if ($_GET["command"]="createacct"))

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error at this line

> 

```
if ($_GET["apikey"]=="$api_get"){
```

you can print this two values before comparing.
For debugging check both variables values like

```html
var_dump($_GET["apikey"]);
var_dump($api_get);
```

also compare like this

```html
if ($_GET["apikey"]== $api_get) {
```

Comment: I am getting no_key response instead of wrong_key. That means ```(isset($_GET["apikey"]))``` this condition gets false. I did ```echo($_GET["apikey"]);``` in the starting of PHP file. When I write wrong credentials, I get apikey printed in response but when I write correct credentials, I get ```< br / >
    <
    b > Notice < /b>:  Undefined index: apikey in <b>/var / www / html / admin / api / auth.php < /b> on line <b>7</b > < br / > {
        "response": "no_key"
    }```